# Advanced Linking of cells with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

OK this is a feature I have really wanted for sometime now. Trying to solve this in VBA and it's going no where. I want to link cells together. Not Just in A1 "=B1". But If I change the value in either one it will change the other one. I  Problem is I can not change the value of A1 in that scenario since that will write over the formula. So I want a true link. This could be very helpful. So Far I have gotten it to work but I can't get it to work across multiple tabs. Here is the code that works if on the same sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngA1 As Range
    Dim rngC5 As Range

    Set rngA1 = Range("A1")
    Set rngC5 = Range("C5")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rngA1, rngC5)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = rngA1.Address Then
            rngC5.Value = rngA1.Value
        Else
            rngA1.Value = rngC5.Value
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried to change the ranges to include the sheet but it doesn't work. Also I have to do this in the Sheet not in the module. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Thisworkbook` module:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim arrGroups, i As Long, m, tgt, arr, grp
    
    'all groups of cells to be synced
    arrGroups = Array(Array("Sheet1|D3", "Sheet2|B4"), _
                      Array("Sheet1|F3", "Sheet2|D4", "Sheet3|F7"))
    
    tgt = Sh.Name & "|" & Target.Address(False, False)
    
    For Each grp In arrGroups              'loop through the groups of synced cells
        m = Application.Match(tgt, grp, 0) 'matches one of the synced cells in this group?
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For i = LBound(grp) To UBound(grp)
                If grp(i) <> tgt Then 'skip the cell raising the event...
                    arr = Split(grp(i), "|")
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)).Range(arr(1)).Value = Target.Value
                End If
            Next i
            Application.EnableEvents = False
        End If
    Next grp
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: added the ability to specify more than one synced group of cells

Comment: I copied and pasted directly and no changes were made. Added a value into Sheet1 D3 and nothing changed on Sheet2. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me.  Make sure events are turned on (put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate pane and press Enter) and that you put the code in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: The idea is brilliant but OP looks to want two-way one to one synchronization...

Comment: @FaneDuru - that’s what this is?   Only it allows for >2 cells per group of cells, and multiple groups of cells.

Comment: I understood what (and how) it does, but I am afraid that his expectation were to have one to one and could not understand what to place in each array of the jagged array. At least, this is what I think. He should explain better what it does against his expectations... Based on idea to use this event I also placed an answer, allowing one to one linking, but he did not say anything, neither...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution: 1) Must create sheet named range for each cell of  each GROUP OF LINKED CELLS, with this naming convention: e.g. for group1 the names are: anything, anything.1, anything.2 and anything.3,  for a secont group the names are LINK1, LINK1.1, LINK1.2 LINK1.3. These sheet named ranges can live in any sheet and their names must are different after the "."
In every sheet must have code like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("LINK1"), Me.Range("LINK1.1"), Me.Range("LINK1.2"))) Is Nothing Then
      Call synchronizeLinkedCells(Target, "LINK1")
   End If
End Sub
```

and in a module write this:

```
Public Sub synchronizeLinkedCells(r As Range, rname As String)
   Dim nm As Name, p As Integer
   
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
       If InStr(1, nm.Name, rname) > 0 Then
           Range(nm.Name).Value = r.Value
       End If
   Next nm
Lerr:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This way you can easily organize connected groups of cells that may belong to different sheets, easily adding and modifying the groups... In the example think the "LINK1" as the group id, and the "LINK1.1" .... "LINK1.n" as the group members in any sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. **Most of the credit should go to @Tim Williams**, for his brilliant idea, of using `Workbook_SheetChange` event. The code uses a jagged array (as his one does), but each array is synchronized with each other by their element position. I only adapted his code:

```
Option Explicit

    
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim arrGroups, tgt As String, m, n, arr
    
    'arrays (of jagged array) are syicronzed as first witht first, second with second and so on:
    'Sheet1("D3") sync with Sheet2("F3"), Sheet2("B4") sync with Sheet3("F7"), Sheet3("C5") sync with Sheet1("D4")
    arrGroups = Array(Array("Sheet1|D3", "Sheet2|B4", "Sheet3|C5"), Array("Sheet2|F3", "Sheet3|F7", "Sheet1|D4")) 'use here what you need syncing
                     
    
    tgt = Sh.Name & "|" & Target.Address(False, False)
    
    'check to see in which array of the jagged array a match exists, if any:
    m = Application.Match(tgt, arrGroups(0), 0)
    n = Application.Match(tgt, arrGroups(1), 0)
    
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          arr = Split(arrGroups(1)(m - 1), "|")
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)).Range(arr(1)).Value = Target.Value
    ElseIf Not IsError(n) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          arr = Split(arrGroups(0)(n - 1), "|")
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)).Range(arr(1)).Value = Target.Value
    End If
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @John Velella Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/ph16qs) a testing workbook using the above code. I similarly colored the interior of synchronized cells, to easily follow their change...

Answer (score 0):

### A Workbook SheetChange: Multiple Cells In Multiple Worksheets

- Only the value of the 'first' (left and top-most) intersecting cell is considered, i.e. with this setup, if in worksheet `Sheet1`, cells `A2:C2` contain the values `1,2,3` respectively, and they are copied to `A1:C1`, all the cells designated by the arrays will change to `1` since `A1` is the 'first' intersecting cell (opposed to `C1`; `B1` is irrelevant but will change to `2`).

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim wsNames(): wsNames = VBA.Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet1", "Sheet3")
    Dim wsCells(): wsCells = VBA.Array("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1")
    
    Dim wsIndexes: wsIndexes = Application.Match(wsNames, Array(Sh.Name), 0)
    If Application.Count(wsIndexes) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(wsNames)
    
    Dim tCell As Range, n As Long, tFound As Boolean

    For n = 0 To nUpper
        If IsNumeric(wsIndexes(n + 1)) Then
            Set tCell = Sh.Range(wsCells(n))
            If Not Intersect(tCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    If n > nUpper Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim tValue: tValue = tCell.Value
    Dim wsIndex As Long: wsIndex = n
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    
    For n = 0 To nUpper
        If n <> wsIndex Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Set dws = Me.Sheets(wsNames(n))
            On Error GoTo ClearError
            If Not dws Is Nothing Then
                dws.Range(wsCells(n)).Value = tValue
                Set dws = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next n
    
ProcExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```